# Matlab script can't count categorical variable correctly based on value from another column

Tags: matlab, count

I have this script to count the number of true segments (column3 "Segment Good") for each category ("go", "nogo" under column 1), but it never returns the actual number  :(

I would appreciate to have another pairs of eyes to look at it! Thank you!

(This .txt file is converted from .log file from EGI netstation if it matters)

sample .txt file:

> ```
> category  Segment number   Segment Good   Eye movements
> go          1                true          true
> go          2                false        false
> go          3                true          true
> go          4                false        false
> nogo        1                true          true
> nogo        2                false        false
> ```

```
    Files2 = dir(strcat('/Users/EGI/GoNogo2/log22/','*.txt'));
lengthFiles2 = length(Files2);

for ff = 1:lengthFiles2
    ff
    try
        filename = Files2(ff).name;
        idx=strfind(filename,'_');
        name{ff} = filename(1:idx(1)-1); 
        path = strcat('/Users/EGI/GoNogo2/log22/',filename);
        data = readtable(path);
        category = data(:,1);
        segmentgood = data(:,3);

        record = zeros(size(category,1),2);


        for i=1:size(category,1)
                                 
                tt = category(i,1).Category{1};
           
        if strcmp(tt,'go')

                record(i,1)=1;
        elseif strcmp(tt,'nogo')

                record(i,2)=1;
       
        end

        end


        segment = zeros(size(segmentgood,1),2);


        for i=1:size(category,1)
           
                tt = segmentgood(i,1).SegmentGood{1};
           

            if strcmp(tt,'true')

                    segment(i,1)=1;
            elseif strcmp(tt,'false')

                    segment(i,2)=1;

            end

        end

        goTrue = 0;
        nogoTrue=0;
        

        for i=1:size(category,1)
          if record(i,1)==1&segment(i,1)==1
              goTrue=goTrue+1;
          else record(i,2)==1&segment(i,1)==1

                nogoTrue=nogoTrue+1;
         
          end

        end

        result(ff,1:2) = [goTrue nogoTrue];

        result2(ff,1:2) = [sum(record)];
    end
end

results = {};
results2={};
for i=1:lengthFiles2

  results {i,1} = name{i};
  results {i,2} = result(i,1);
  results {i,3} = result(i,2);
  %results {i,4} = result(i,3);
  results2 {i,1} = name{i};
  results2 {i,2} = result2(i,1);
  results2 {i,3} = result2(i,2);
 % results2 {i,4} = result2(i,3);

end

xlswrite('/Users/EGI/Desktop/log2/.xls',results,'results');
```

Comment: Precisely, which output parameters do you want to evaluate?  Do you only want the number of times true appears in column 3? For the `sample.txt` could you happen to give the expected output?

Comment: Yes! I want the number of times true appears in column 3 for each category. Thanks for the solution! I'll try it once I have access to matlab.

Comment: No, problem. Hope it all works well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief Explanation and Preface:

Not too exactly sure of all the implementation requirements of this task but here is a method of reading `.txt`/`.log` files. It uses the function `textscan()` to scan the file into MATLAB as a cell array with each data entry formatted as `%s %d %s %s` (string, integer, string, string).

**Category:** string → `%s` 
**Segment Number:** integer → `%d` 
**Segment Good:** string → `%s` 
**Eye Movements:** string → `%s`

After reading this data as a cell array denoted as `Data` in the script below we can split this array into columns. Now we can check which indices/rows have the "Category" `go` and `nogo` by using the `contains()` function. The contains function will take in two arguments. The first argument is the string/array of strings that are being searched and the second argument is the string to search for. The `contains()` function will return true "1" for all the indices where it can find the string to search for:

**Example:**

```
Result = contains(["Apple", "Pear", "Grape", "Apple"],"Apple");
```

**will return**

```
Result = [1 0 1 0];
```

After evaluating the indices corresponding to `go` and `nogo` we can matrix index the third column using these values. Matrix indexing allows us to grab all the indices corresponding to a condition/using a logical array. In this case, our logical array/condition was the indices pertaining to `nogo` and `go`. Applying `contains(,"true")` to these new subsets will allow us to find where true occurs given each category `go` and `nogo`. Finally using the function `nnz()` (number of non-zeroes) will allow you to find how many ones/times `contains()` returned true.

---

[image: Results of Counting True Cases]

### Script:

```
clear;
clc;

%Reading in the data as a cell array%
fileID = fopen('sample.log', 'r');

Header = string(fgetl(fileID));
Data = textscan(fileID,'%s %d %s %s');

fclose(fileID);

%Splitting the data into specific columns%
Category = Data(:,1);
Category = string(Category{1,1});
Segment_Number = Data(:,2); 
Segment_Number = string(Segment_Number{1,1});
Segment_Good = Data(:,3);
Segment_Good = string(Segment_Good{1,1});
Eye_Movements = Data(:,4);
Eye_Movements = string(Eye_Movements{1,1});


%Finding the indices corresponding to "go" and "nogo"%
No_Go_Indices = contains(Category,"nogo");
Go_Indices = ~No_Go_Indices;

%Finding how many true cases in column 3 (Segment_Good) corresponding to "go" and "nogo"
Go_True_Cases = nnz(contains(Segment_Good(Go_Indices),"true"));
No_Go_True_Cases = nnz(contains(Segment_Good(No_Go_Indices),"true"));


%Counting the number of times true occurs in each column%
Column_3_True_Count = nnz(contains(Segment_Good,"true"));
Column_4_True_Count = nnz(contains(Eye_Movements,"true"));

%Printing the results to the command window%
fprintf("Category: go -> %d true\n",Go_True_Cases);
fprintf("Category: nogo -> %d true\n\n",No_Go_True_Cases);

fprintf("Total true cases: %d\n", Column_3_True_Count);
```

---

### Extension: Looping Through Files in a Directory

```
clear;
clc;

%Full or relative directory path%

%Adding directory with the files to the be accessible%
Directory_Path = "Files"; 
addpath(Directory_Path);

%Reading the filenames within the directory and the number of files%
Text_Files = dir(Directory_Path+'/*.txt');
Number_Of_Files = length(Text_Files);

%Creating arrays that will hold the results%
All_No_Go_True_Cases = zeros(Number_Of_Files,1);
All_Go_True_Cases = zeros(Number_Of_Files,1);

%Looping through the files and running the function that will grab the
%results%
for File_Index = 1: Number_Of_Files

File_Name = string(Text_Files(File_Index).name);


[No_Go_True_Cases,Go_True_Cases] = Get_Data(File_Name);
All_No_Go_True_Cases(File_Index) = No_Go_True_Cases;
All_Go_True_Cases(File_Index) = Go_True_Cases;

end

All_No_Go_True_Cases
All_Go_True_Cases


%Local function definition%
function [No_Go_True_Cases,Go_True_Cases] = Get_Data(File_Name)
%Reading in the data as a cell array%
fileID = fopen(File_Name, 'r');

Header = string(fgetl(fileID));
Data = textscan(fileID,'%s %d %s %s');

fclose(fileID);

%Splitting the data into specific columns%
Category = Data(:,1);
Category = string(Category{1,1});
Segment_Number = Data(:,2); 
Segment_Number = string(Segment_Number{1,1});
Segment_Good = Data(:,3);
Segment_Good = string(Segment_Good{1,1});
Eye_Movements = Data(:,4);
Eye_Movements = string(Eye_Movements{1,1});


%Finding the indices corresponding to "go" and "nogo"%
No_Go_Indices = contains(Category,"nogo");
Go_Indices = ~No_Go_Indices;

%Finding how many true cases in column 3 (Segment_Good) corresponding to "go" and "nogo"
Go_True_Cases = nnz(contains(Segment_Good(Go_Indices),"true"));
No_Go_True_Cases = nnz(contains(Segment_Good(No_Go_Indices),"true"));


%Counting the number of times true occurs in each column%
Column_3_True_Count = nnz(contains(Segment_Good,"true"));
Column_4_True_Count = nnz(contains(Eye_Movements,"true"));

%Printing the results to the command window%
fprintf("Category: go -> %d true\n",Go_True_Cases);
fprintf("Category: nogo -> %d true\n",No_Go_True_Cases);
fprintf("Total true cases: %d\n\n", Column_3_True_Count);
end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: The code works! Thank you! But I have trouble adapting it to my original script posted above so that it loops through all files in a folder and return the outcome in a table. No worries if it'll take you some time but any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Sophy glad it worked. :) I added the part that loops through files within a folder. In this case, I did `.txt` files but you could also incorporate `.log` files. The script will be in the `Extension` section within my answer.